# How to get result from adb shell input text?

Tags: android, adb

I want to know if the command I use is working properly.

```
adb shell input text 1232112
```

As here, I want to enter the text into EditText, and I want to know if the input text is successful, or is it another interface element (ex Button).
How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try to get the screen dump with uiautomator and search for your string.

Comment: @TDG: it's a good option but not work in my case. seems like my activity does not share my string to uiautomator, so I can't find my string.